# compile error in for loop getting group role membership

Tags: apex, soql, developer-console, role-hierarchy, compile-error

I need to get all members including members associated by their roles of a group passed in and am having trouble with the below code:

```
List<String> roleRelatedGroupIds = new List<String>();
        for (Group g : [SELECT id, RelatedId, Type FROM Group where RelatedId= :UserInfo.getUserRoleId()]){
            roleRelatedGroupIds.add(g.id);
        }
        List<String> allGroupIDs = new List<String>();

   for (GroupMember gm : [SELECT Id, group.id, group.name, group.type FROM GroupMember where (UserOrGroupId = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND group.type='Regular') OR (UserOrGroupId IN :roleRelatedGroupIds AND group.type='Regular')]
             {
                allGroupIDs.add(gm.group.id);     
             }        
    }
```

I am hoping to be able to get all the members whether they are direct or indirectly associated by their roles, but my code will not compile in Developer console.

I am getting an error `unexpected token '{'` on the line

> for (Group g : [SELECT id, RelatedId, Type FROM Group where RelatedId= :UserInfo.getUserRoleId()]){

what am I doing wrong?

I am totally stuck just compiling my code before I find out if this is the right way to get all members of a public group as well as all members associated by their roles...

Comment: @Ratan: no you solved it, thanks for your help...now I am trying to get all indirect members of a group associated through their roles by traversing the role hierarchy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You for loop is not closed.. You need to add `)` at last

```
for (GroupMember gm : [SELECT Id, group.id, group.name, group.type 
                        FROM GroupMember 
                       where (UserOrGroupId = :UserInfo.getUserId() 
                              AND group.type='Regular') 
                          OR (UserOrGroupId IN :roleRelatedGroupIds 
                              AND group.type='Regular')])
 {
    //rest code here
 }
```